# trigger a google marker in one iframe by click a link from other iframe

Tags: javascript, google-maps, iframe, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to trigger a google marker to display the infowindow in one iframe ("mapframe")by clicking a link from other iframe("linkframe"). 
I have add this function to the link in "linkframe" once clicked but it does not work.

```
<a href="javascript: myFunction();">click here</a>    
<script>
    function myFunction() {
    var mapframe =window.parent.document.getElementById("mapframe").contentWindow;
    mapframe.google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[1],'click');
    }
    </script>
```

If i combine two frame's content together. the link written like below works well though:

```
<a href="javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[1],'click');">Click HERE</a>
```

Anyone can give some advice? Thanks very much!
"mapframe" is the id of the map's frame

Comment: Try: `mapframe.google.maps.event.trigger(mapframe.gmarkers[1],'click');`

Comment: Thanks for reply but it does not work..

Answer (score 0):

oh, i found the solution.

I put this function in the link frame

```
<a href="javascript: myFunction(1);">CLICK</a>
<script>
  function myFunction(number) {
  parent.frames['mapframe'].clickyeah(number);
    }
</script>
```

I put this function in the map frame

```
function clickyeah(number)
{
google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[number],'click');
}
```